# F# functions implementing polynomial arithmetic

Tags: f#

I have a couple of functions for doing basic arithmetic on polynomials.

```
let rec mulC x ys =
match (x,ys) with
| (_,[])                    -> []
| (x,y::ys) when x > 0    -> x * y::mulC x ys

let rec addE xs ys =
match (xs, ys) with
| ([],[])                   -> []
| ([], y::ys)            -> y::ys
| (x::xs,[])             -> x::xs
| (x::xs, y::ys)      -> (x + y) :: addE xs ys

let mulX xs = 
match xs with
| []                    -> []
| xs                    -> 0::xs

let rec mul qs = function
| []                    -> []
| x::tail               -> addE (mulC x qs)
                                (mulX(mul qs tail))
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a better place for this question and you seem to have copied it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511745) already. I suggest you delete this one.

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic], we cannot review broken code, not can we explain how/why code behavior. Since this is already cross-posted with Stack Overflow, I have taken the liberty to remove the off-topic portion of the question, and kept the working version for open-ended critique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> | (x,y::ys) when x > 0    -> x * y::mulC x ys
> ```

> ```
> | (x::xs, y::ys)      -> (x + y) :: addE xs ys
> ```

Why the inconsistency in parentheses and whitespace? For what it's worth, I think the second is more readable.

---

> ```
> let rec mulC x ys =
> match (x,ys) with
> | (_,[])                    -> []
> | (x,y::ys) when x > 0    -> x * y::mulC x ys
> ```

What about the case `x = 0`, `ys` is non-empty? Don't you get a warning? (I also find it odd that the test is `>`. I infer that you're only intending to handle non-negative coefficients, but that seems like an unnecessary restriction).

---

> ```
> let rec addE xs ys =
> match (xs, ys) with
> | ([],[])                   -> []
> | ([], y::ys)            -> y::ys
> | (x::xs,[])             -> x::xs
> | (x::xs, y::ys)      -> (x + y) :: addE xs ys
> ```

There's no need to pattern-match a structure if you're not using the structure. This could be simplified to

```
let rec addE xs ys =
  match (xs, ys) with
  | ([], ys)            -> ys
  | (xs,[])             -> xs
  | (x::xs, y::ys)      -> (x + y) :: addE xs ys
```

---

Why are the three auxiliary functions in the top-level scope? I admit that I don't know F#, but the languages that it's heavily inspired by would allow them to be defined in a `let` clause inside the definition of `mul`, keeping the top-level namespace clean.